# Adding to an index of authors

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite but have programmed in BASIC (and other languages) for pushing 50 years.

Given the sample code extract, please offer suggestions for improvement:

```
    Sub addAuthor(ByVal authorlnf As String, ByVal authorfnf As String)
        Dim objConn As SQLiteConnection
        Dim objCommand As SQLiteCommand
        objConn = New SQLiteConnection(CONNECTION_STR)
        objConn.Open()
        objCommand = objConn.CreateCommand()
        objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [author] ([authorlnf], [authorfnf]) VALUES ('" & authorlnf & "', '" & authorfnf & "');"
        Try
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As SQLiteException
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        If Not IsNothing(objConn) Then objConn.Close()

End Sub
```

This is an index of book authors and this routine will be called several thousand times. I'm replacing VB dictionaries as memory is becoming a limiting factor.

Comment: You should consider opening a database connection to be an extremely costly operation. You really don't want to do that often at all. Also look into prepared statements and bulk inserts - I don't know VB or that API, so can't give specific advice, sorry.

Comment: I'm beginning to come to that conclusion.  The impression I had gotten probably from those using sqlite in multi-user situations is to open/close it to avoid deadlock situations.  Since this a single user instance I think it's time to look at how/when I'm opening "things".  The real acid test is when I start to do look up on the tables.  I expect some degradation over dictionaries - but if I can reduce that impact to a tolerable level then I'm open to any ideas.

Answer (score 7):

I have never used SQLite either, but something is jumping at me in your code: the `addAuthor()` procedure **owns the connection**, which means if you're calling it 10,000 times in a loop you're going to be opening and closing 10,000 connections, which is ..well to be honest, *nuts*.

Looking at the method's signature:

```
Sub addAuthor(ByVal authorlnf As String, ByVal authorfnf As String)
```

#### Naming nitpicks

- I believe **PascalCasing** is the convention for naming just about everything in VB, but what really matters is *consistency*. Try to be consistent with the language you're using - the VB API uses PascalCasing for methods.
- Names `authorlnf` and `authorfnf` could just as well be named `authorwtf` - they tell the reader it's something about an *author*, but to find out *what* exactly, one has to dig deeper than the method's signature. **Avoid disemvoweling at all costs** - it ruins reading even the best-written code base.
  <sub>well now that I think of it I'd say `authorlnf` would be author's *last name* and `authorfnf` would be author's *first name*.. still scratching my head as for what the last `f` is standing for...</sub>

---

#### Serious stuff

What happens when `authorlnf` contains the value `"Robert'); DROP TABLE author;--"`?

[image: little bobby tables]
<sub>credits: xkcd/Randall Munroe</sub>

Your `insert` fails and the `author` table gets dropped (if your user has the permissions *and* there's no FK constraint involved, but that's not the point). This is called *SQL Injection* and, depending on where, how and by whom your code is being used, it may or may not be a concern - nevertheless, it's a *flaw* in your design.

You could write yourself some [parameter-cleansing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters) and think you're protected, but that would leave *you* the burden of proving that *your* cleansing function is undeniably safe. And you must never forget to call it!

Or you could [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477872/inserting-into-sqlite-database-with-parameters-from-vb-net), *that take the value of the user input*. That's **much** harder to mess with!

---

#### Connection ownership

I think the `AddAuthor()` method shouldn't create (/own) the connection it's using. Consider this:

```
Sub AddAuthor(ByVal connection As SQLiteConnection, ByVal authorlnf As String, ByVal authorfnf As String)
```

All of a sudden, opening, closing and disposing the connection is no longer a concern here: you put that burden on the caller, where you're looping 10,000 times - so you open up the connection, create and execute 10,000 commands inside `AddAuthor()`, and then close the connection. That puts the *lite* in SQLite, no?

---

I'll only add that you're catching known & relevant exceptions and letting unknown ones bubble up, **and that's excellent**. The only thing is, as @Malachi correctly pointed out, you should be closing the connection in a `Finally` block, but if your method doesn't own the connection, that's moot. However I believe a `Command` would implement `IDisposable`, so it should be `.Dispose()`'d.

Comment: And now I understand that cartoon strip. :-)

Comment: using parameters is nice, but if they do enter something like `'); DROP TABLE Students;--` that just means that the insert or update to the Database won't cause an issue, what if that column is used in another query that isn't as safe as the input from the application/website?  it could still cause issues, so you still need to filter out some characters and limit the input into the database.

Comment: @Malachi `"'); DROP TABLE Students;--"` would be treated as any other string.. if all *executable* SQL statements use parameters, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't closing the connection inside of a `finally` statement which means that in the case  your application hits one of those exceptions it will not close the connection.  this isn't good.

I recommend using a `using` block to surround the code that you need performed by a connection. something like this

```
 Sub addAuthor(ByVal authorlnf As String, ByVal authorfnf As String)
    Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO [author] ([authorlnf], [authorfnf]) VALUES ('" & authorlnf & "', '" & authorfnf & "');"

    Using objConn As New SQLiteConnection(CONNECTION_STR)
        Dim objCommand As New SQLiteCommand(cmdText,objConn)
        objConn.Open()
        Try
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As SQLiteException
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

The syntax for the SQLite VB code may be incorrect, I was basing it off of the Syntax for SQL Server commands thinking that they would be similar.

---

If SQLite follows the same usage as SQL Server then @Mat'sMug is right and command also implements `IDisposable` so you could write it like this

```
 Sub addAuthor(ByVal authorlnf As String, ByVal authorfnf As String)
    Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO [author] ([authorlnf], [authorfnf]) VALUES ('" & authorlnf & "', '" & authorfnf & "');"

    Using objConn As New SQLiteConnection(CONNECTION_STR)
        Using objCommand As New SQLiteCommand(cmdText, objConn)
            objConn.Open()
            Try
                objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
            Catch ex As SQLiteException
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I assumed that you already take care of possible SQL Injection in other code before sending the parameters to this sub

Comment: Screening strings for offensive sql is just partly addressing potential sql injection. Using full-fledged parameters is the safest way I know. That said I don't know sqlite either :)